# Is it possible that the Execute SQL Statement simultaneously works with SQL Statement and with Variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, task, execute

Is it possible to design the Execute SQL Task such that when it reads from SQL's database ,  task A executed and when it reads from variables , task B executed? It means that the Execute SQL Task simultaneously works with SQL Statement and with Variables .

Comment: I am not 100% sure to understand your question, but you can ofc start table functions, scalar functions and stored procedures to fullfil you task. So task A is a stored proc, and task B as well, then you can do start them any time.

Comment: I don't understand your reply unfortunately . How can I set the Execute SQL Task's option such as ResultSet or SQLStatement ? How can I write the appropriate query in order that when I change it , the Execute SQL Task know that it must use SQlStatement or Variables which we set in ssis ?

Comment: To execute statements you can use this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx, but you probably need to learn how to use stored procedures then imho. Have a look here http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/160/sql-server-stored-procedure/

Comment: To restate: Task A is an Execute SQL Task that generates a resultset which is written to an SSIS Variable. Your question is how can I use that Variable in a subsequent Execute SQL Task?

Comment: Have I understood your question? I'd like to help but I'd need clarification on your problem domain.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the SqlStatementSource property of an Execute SQL task to be set at runtime depending on whether you retrieve a value from a SQL database. If no value is retrieved, you want it set to a pre-existing variable's value.

1. Create an Execute SQL task to retrieve your SQL Database value
   and assign it to variable DatabaseSQL. I'm assuming your query will return NULL if no value is found.
2. Assign your default value to variable DefaultSQL.
3. In your Execute SQL task, create an Expression for the
   SqlStatementSource property and set the expression to

   REPLACENULL(@User::DatabaseSQL, @User::DefaultSQL)